# Rotate video not woking as expect

Tags: swift, rotation

I had function to rotate video, first time I rotate with angle = pi / 2 it working normal, but if I continue rotate it with (pi / 2), it not working, it still only rotate (pi / 2), but I expect it rotate pi. Any one can help me, thanks

```
let rotateTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat((self.rotateAngle * Double.pi)/180))
        let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: sourceURL)
        let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
        let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        var clipVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)

        try? compositionVideoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: videoAsset.duration), of: clipVideoTrack[0], at: .zero)
        compositionVideoTrack?.preferredTransform = videoAsset.preferredTransform
        let videoTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]
        let videoSize = videoTrack.naturalSize
        let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        videoComposition.renderSize = videoSize
        let timeScale = CMTimeScale(videoTrack.nominalFrameRate)
        videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: timeScale)
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: mixComposition.duration)
        let mixVideoTrack = mixComposition.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]
        mixVideoTrack.preferredTransform = rotateTransform
        let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: mixVideoTrack)
        layerInstruction.setTransform(mixVideoTrack.preferredTransform, at: .zero)
        instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
        videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]

        guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition,
                                                       presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough) else {
            return
        }
        exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
        exportSession.outputFileType = .mov
        exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition
        exportSession.exportAsynchronously { [weak self] in
            self?.handleExportSession(exportSession: exportSession, sourceURL: sourceURL, outputURL: outputURL)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the transform, this will always be applied to the original orientation. So when you set a rotation matrix by pi/2, the original will be rotated by pi/2. If you apply the same rotation matrix again, the *original* will be rotated again by pi/2. What you need is to combine the current transform with the new rotation and then set that resulting transformation.

Something like:

```
let currentTransform = mixVideoTrack.preferredTransform // or whereever you get it from
let newTransform = currentTransform.rotated(by: CGFloat((self.rotateAngle * Double.pi)/180))
mixVideoTrack.preferredTransform = newTransform
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but when I debug, I found that the currentTransform is not change after I rotate, it alway get: ▿ CGAffineTransform
  - a : 1.0
  - b : 0.0
  - c : 0.0
  - d : 1.0
  - tx : 0.0
  - ty : 0.0

Comment: I'm not an expert in AV stuff, so I would suggest that you store the current transform in an extra property inside your class, and take this to calculate the resulting matrix.

Comment: Cannot assign to property: 'preferredTransform' is a get-only property